# Access custom theme settings from within views

Tags: theming, views

I have a few custom theme settings which so on my themes settings page.. this all works fine and as expected.

I now need to create a view that gets that custom theme setting. I can't find anything on how to do this.

I have installed the views php module and I know this `theme_get_setting('setting_name')` is what i used to get the theme settings in my `template.php` file.

Any help with this will be much appreciated.

Regards
C

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you're trying to do?  If you want to theme the view, you can always make a template.

Comment: Hi Patrick. I know how to create a template but I'm stuck on getting a custom theme setting from the database. It's that variable that I need to use in my view/template. I hope that makes more sense.

Comment: do want make some pages like `customize theme` for non-admin user?

Comment: No... I have store custom theme settings in the database via the `theme-settings.php`. This is all working. I just need to be able to use that stores variable (that is now in the database) in my view/ view template.

Comment: is this on the right track: `$conf ~ developer/globals.php ~ Array of persistent variables stored in 'variable' table.`

Comment: How exactly is theme_get_setting() not working for you? Are you getting an error message or a different output than expected?

Comment: Hi @sheena_d I installed the `views_php` module and added the following php code: `<?php print theme_get_setting('tm_qrule_url'); ?>` but got no result and no error. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try adding the name of the theme that has that setting as the second value passed to the function? i.e. `theme_get_setting('tm_qrule_url', 'themename');`?

Comment: `<?php print theme_get_setting('tm_qrule_url'); ?>` works. It doesn't show in the views preview but does in the actual page load. @sheena_d... thanks for getting me to recheck that.. otherwise I would have missed it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for other people who come across this here is the answer:

`<?php print theme_get_setting('tm_qrule_url'); ?>` works using the `views_php` module

It doesn't show in the views preview but does in the actual page load.

Thanks goes to @sheena_d for helping with this.